# Pass multiple values with http GET from Angular2 to php

Tags: php, angular

Am using Angular2 as front end and php as my server script . I want to pass the user login details to server with the http.get() .

I used like..

```
var uname = event.email;
var pass = event.password;
this.http
.get('http://192.168.0.100:80/php/logincheck.php?user='+uname+'&pwd='+pass).subscribe();
```

but it can't get the 2 values. I can simply pass a single value easily.
If 2 values can be passed like this. Please help ..

Comment: seems dangerous to pass them over http

Comment: why ? Is there any other possible solution ?@ nogad

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
import { URLSearchParams, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

getLogin() {
    const options: BaseRequestOptions = new BaseRequestOptions();
    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('uname', event.email);
    params.set('pass', event.password);
    options.search = params;

    return this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:80/php/logincheck.php', options)
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Server side :

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['uname'];
?>
```

or

```
$url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url['query'], $queryParams);
echo $queryParams['uname'];
echo $queryParams['pass'];
```

Comment: thanks for your Response @chandru . How can I access this options at Php server side ??

Comment: Now it works..! I made a small change , use .subscribe() instead of .map() thanks@chandru

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is secured to send a password without doing some sort of encrypting. but if you want to send some data to your server request it is possible to send them in the request headers as well. see below code snippet.

```
//on import section
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

//inside your login function
let requestUrl= "http://192.168.0.100:80/php/logincheck.php"   
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'email': event.email,
'pwd': event.password }); 

this.http.get(requestUrl, this.requestOptions).subscribe();
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of php, refer artticle on below link, on how to read request headers http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php